# Vector on upper half of hemisphere

Tags: c++, math, vector-graphics, glm-math

I have a normal vector `N`, which defines the upper half of an hemisphere and an function, which creates random points `P` on the hemisphere.

Now I want to know, if the randomly choosen point is on the upper half. Is it save to assume, if the length of `N+P` is greater or equal 1, `P` is on the upper half, or is there a better way to calculate this in `glm`?

Comment: point `P` is in desired hemisphere if `dot_product(hemishpere_dir,P) > 0` considering that the sphere has the center in the origine (0,0,0)

Comment: @Raxvan this seems to be correct, but I'm wondering if `glm::length(N, P) >= 1` is also correct (for normalized vectors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Raxvan gave a perfectly valid answer how to do it properly: use [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) and check if it is positive (non-negative).

Answering your original idea that you also re-stated in the comments:

> if the length of `N+P` is greater or equal 1, `P` is on the upper half

this is an incorrect way. Yes this test returns "true" for all the correct points but it does not filter out all the incorrect points. For example, consider `N` is `(0,0,1)` (i.e. vector along Z-axis) and `P` is `(0.99, 0, -0.14)` (i.e. a vector just a bit below the XY-plane and at the far end along the X-axis). Obviously `P` is not in the "upper hemisphere" but `N + P` is `(0.99, 0, 0.86)` and its length is obviously more than 1.

Comment: In your example you don't use normalized vectors, but even if, your example is still correct - thanks

Comment: @Philipp, I'm not sure what you mean when you say that "_you don't use normalized vectors_". Obviously length of `N` is exactly `1` and `P` is quite close to `1` and is not exactly `1` only because I truncated the value of `-sqrt(1 - 0.99^2)` at two decimal digits to `-0.14`